# Restart variable every day

Tags: rtc

How can I restart a variable every day? I have an RTC1307. The problem is that I can't use an alarm event because the Arduino will be shut down during that hour. So I need a more reliable solution.

Will this work? A date could be an integer?

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

int  lastDay;
int EE_ADDR = 0;
int totalLitres;

void setup() {
  EEPROM.get(EE_ADDR, lastDay);
}

void loop() {
DateTime now;
  if (now.day() != lastDay) // this happens exactly once a day.
    totalLitres = 0; // reset the accumulated volume

  lastDay = now.day();
}
```

Comment: Why does your Arduino shut down? And is your intention to prevent the shut down from happening?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem ... if the Arduino is shut down, it will restart and the variable gets its initial value again.

Comment: Ya, you gotta be a little more clear.   You want to zero a variable every day but there is a chance the arduino is not running when the new day starts?   One option would be to store a "lastResetDay" variable in EEPROM.  Then on startup, and periodically in your code, you will pull them variable from EEPROM, check it against the current day value from the RTC, if they match-do nothing. If they dont match then zero the flow variable and strore the current day back in EEPROM.

Comment: think about what will happen if the day changes right after the `if` statement compares the two values

Comment: @jsotola: Nothing special will happen: `now.day()` does not change by itself. `DateTime` is nothing but a container for timestamp items (year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds). If you don't explicitly initialize it, is gets default-initialized to 2000-01-01T00:00:00 (the default used to be 2106-02-06T06:28:16, until [this pull request](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/pull/93) got accepted).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Since your RTC has some non-volatile RAM (NVRAM) onboard, you could
  use it instead of the EEPROM. This way you will not have to worry
  about the EEPROM endurance.
- If there is the possibility that the device gets power-cycled within a
  single day, you probably want it to preserve the liter count. This can
  be achieved by periodically saving this count to the NVRAM, and
  restoring it at startup. You can save often, as you don't have
  endurance limits.
- If the device is started after a full month of being off, if should
  notice some days have passed, even it the day number is the same as
  when it was turned off. Instead of saving just the day number, I would
  store the total number of days elapsed since 2000 Jan 1.

Untested implementation of the above suggestions:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

const uint32_t NVRAM_UPDATE_PERIOD = 10000;  // 10 seconds

/* Addresses for data items saved in the RTC's NVRAM. */
const uint8_t ADDRESS_LITERS    = 0x00;
const uint8_t ADDRESS_RESET_DAY = 0x02;

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
uint16_t liters;
uint16_t reset_day;

/*
 * If `liters' has not been reset today, reset it now and update both
 * the RAM and NVRAM copies of `reset_day'.
 */
void reset_liters_if_needed()
{
    uint16_t current_day = rtc.now().secondstime() / 86400;
    if (current_day > reset_day) {
        liters = 0;
        reset_day = current_day;
        rtc.writenvram(ADDRESS_RESET_DAY,
                (uint8_t *) &reset_day, sizeof reset_day);
    }
}

void setup()
{
    /* Pull the initial `liters' and `rest_day' from NVRAM. */
    rtc.begin();
    rtc.readnvram((uint8_t *) &liters, sizeof liters,
            ADDRESS_LITERS);
    rtc.readnvram((uint8_t *) &reset_day, sizeof reset_day,
            ADDRESS_RESET_DAY);
    reset_liters_if_needed();
}

void loop()
{
    /* Periodically update the NVRAM. */
    static uint32_t last_nvram_update;
    if (millis() - last_nvram_update >= NVRAM_UPDATE_PERIOD) {
        reset_liters_if_needed();
        rtc.writenvram(ADDRESS_LITERS,
                (uint8_t *) &liters, sizeof liters);
    }
}
```

For extra safety you may want to add a large capacitor in order to keep
the Arduino powered for a few milliseconds after being unplugged. And a
circuit that detects when it gets unplugged in order to immediately save
the data and stop accessing the NVRAM before it gets out of juice. This
kind of trick has already been discussed here, you should be able to
find the relevant questions and answers.

Comment: @santilococo: Just beware that a float is 4 bytes. If you store `liters` as a float at address 0, you can put `reset_day` at address 4, but not at address 2.

Comment: @santilococo: No, `sizeof(float)` is 4.